# What's the difference between [hidden] and [class.hide] in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, hidden

I added multiple instances of a component using `*ngFor`, because I needed all the instances to be available in a QueryList.  I then used `[hidden]` to try to hide some components based on an expression that returned a boolean.  This did not work, but using `[class.hide]` did.  What does `[class.hide]` do that is different from `[hidden]`?  We're worried we may need to modify code elsewhere in the app that uses `[hidden]`.

Comment: Try using `*ngIf` rather than `[hidden]` to show and hide elements inside a `*ngFor` loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide some code examples?

Comment: see a silly example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u4r9gz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. AnyWay, if you use ViewChildren, and *ngIf you has in the QueryList all the elements "visibles"

Comment: @Eliseo In your example `display:flex` for `p` is having more precedence over `hidden` attribute related style from User Agent.

Comment: It's the reason because we must avoid use [hidden]

Answer (score 0):

When using `[hidden]` angular simply sets the [HTML attribute 'hidden'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden)

User agents are supposed to hide elements with this attribute, but the caveat is that if the element has another display style explicitly specified it will get precedence.

> Note: Changing the value of the CSS display property on an element
>   with the hidden attribute overrides the behavior. For instance,
>   elements styled display: flex will be displayed despite the hidden
>   attribute's presence.

In the below example see how `div` is not hidden even when adding `hidden` attribute.

```css
div {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<p hidden> Paragraph - Hide Me</p>
<div hidden> Div - Hide Me</div>
```

> We're worried we may need to modify code elsewhere in the app that
>   uses [hidden]

If you want to go with `hidden` attribute instead of a class, you can simply add style for `hidden` attribute in your css:

```css
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}

div.show {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="show" hidden> Div - Hide Me</div>
```

The idea is to go with one strategy and not mix `[hidden]` and `[class.hide]`

---

`[class.hide]` will simply add/remove the class `hide` to the element, and you are supposed to have added the style rule for `hide` in your CSS. Here the above caveat is not present.

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="hide">Hide Me</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

> What does `[class.hide]` do that is different from `[hidden]`?

Binding to `[hidden]` will conditionally add an attribute [`hidden`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp) to the html element.

### [HTML hidden Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp)

> When present, it specifies that an element is not yet, or is no longer, relevant.
>
> Browsers should not display elements that have the hidden attribute specified.

Binding to `[class.hide]` will conditionally add a class named `hide` to the html element. You would then also need to define a style for class `hide` (in a referenced .css file or in the [component attribute](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#styles)). Because it is a style you can make `.hide` do whatever you want. One example would be this:

```
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

As to which you *should* use depends on context and your end goal. I do not see a problem applying `[hidden]` directly to a component though. If you do have such a problem I would recommend you edit your question and include enough code to create an verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

Using `[hidden]` in angular will compile the template and set the attribute of the HTML element to `hidden`. Any element which has as attribute wouldn't be displayed by the browser.

Also I have created a sample code snippet which uses the `[hidden]` attribute and works fine. https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/a3gdJp